# Power Analysis for Difference in Differences Regression

Tags: regression, sample-size, statistical-power, difference-in-difference

How would you approach conducting a power analysis to estimate how large of a sample you would need to conduct a difference in differences estimate?

For example, for a T-test, I would just set effect size, significance level, and power level and I can calculate the sample size needed.

For a difference in differences, what would be my effect size/ what measure would I be using or looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Burlig, Fiona, Louis Preonas, and Matt Woerman. 2020. “[Panel data and experimental design](https://www.fionaburlig.com/s/BPW_JDE.pdf),” *Journal of Development Economics*, 144, 102458.

There is a Stata package [here](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s458286.html). I am not aware of any other implementations.