# Difference-in-Difference: Statistical Power Test R

Tags: r, sample-size, statistical-power

I am planning on running a natural experiment (difference-in-difference) on some UK Local Authority level mean obesity prevalence data. Sample size is limited by a number of factors and it is therefore unlikely we will identify a statistically significant effect.

I would like to identify the minimum sample size I would need in order to detect a SS effect, based upon power calculations.

I wondered whether I could just use a Paired T Test approach or whether there is something more specific to DID? I am coding in R and was interested if people had a view upon the potential use of functions within the pws package.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/622303/7071.